# Zebra crossing Python Opencv project help.. I'm getting the following error

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a project using opencv to detect crosswalk and provide details to navigate it's a project already done and the link to it is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b-BnqgAI5NY

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Friday the 13th_ The Game_20170527134320.mp4') #load a video

W = cap.get(3) #get width
H = cap.get(4) #get height

#Define a new resolution 
ratio = H/W
W = 800
H = int(W * ratio)

#setup the parameters for saving the processed file
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('processedVideo.mp4',fourcc, 15.0, (int(W),int(H)))

Dx = []
Dy = []
after =0
DxAve =0
Dxold =0
DyAve =0
Dyold =0
i = 0
state = ""

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    img = scipy.misc.imresize(frame, (H,W))

    #np.array(Image.fromarray(frame,(H,W)).resize())
    #draw camera's POV
    cv2.circle(img,(int(W/2),int(H/2)),5,(0,0,255),8)
```

here in the try block I have defined processedFrame properly but in the end it says not defined

```
    try:
        processedFrame,dx,dy = process(img)

        if (i < 6):
            Dx.append(dx)
            Dy.append(dy)
            i=i+1

    else:
        DxAve = sum(Dx)/len(Dx)
        DyAve = sum(Dy)/len(Dy)
        del Dx[:]
        del Dy[:]
        i=0

    if (DyAve > 30) and (abs(DxAve) < 300):        
        #check if the vanishing point and the next vanishing point aren't too far from each other 
        if (((DxAve - Dxold)**2 + (DyAve - Dyold)**2) < 150**2) == True:  ##distance 150 px max 
            cv2.line(img,(int(W/2),int(H/2)),(int(W/2)+int(DxAve),int(H/2)+int(DyAve)),(0,0,255),7)
            
            #walking directions
            if abs(DxAve) < 80 and DyAve > 100 and abs(Dxold-DxAve) < 20:
                state = 'Straight'
                cv2.putText(img,state,(50,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3,(0,0,0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)

            elif DxAve > 80 and DyAve > 100 and abs(Dxold-DxAve) < 20:
                state = 'Right'
                cv2.putText(img,state,(50,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3,(0,0,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)

            elif DxAve < 80 and DyAve > 100 and abs(Dxold-DxAve) < 20:
                state = 'Left'
                cv2.putText(img,state,(50,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3,(0,0,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
        else:
            cv2.line(img,(int(W/2),int(H/2)),(int(W/2)+int(Dxold),int(H/2)+int(Dyold)),(0,0,255),)
        
        #walking directions 
        if state == 'Straight':
            cv2.putText(img,state,(50,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3,(0,0,0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
        else:
            cv2.putText(img,state,(50,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3,(0,0,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)           

        Dxold = DxAve
        Dyold = DyAve

except:
    print('Failed to process frame')

#show & save
img = cv2.imshow('Processed',processedFrame)
out.write(processedFrame)

if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q') or cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('Q'):
    break

out.release()
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Failed to process frame
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ragha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\crosswalk.py", line 280, in <module>
    img = cv2.imshow('Processed',processedFrame)
NameError: name 'processedFrame' is not defined
```

Comment: welcome. please take the [tour] and review [ask]. your question is poorly formatted, which hurts readability and understanding. further, `NameError` indicates that you're new to python, so you should learn about the language and find out how the code is executed. then you'll know why that identifier wasn't defined yet when that line was executed.

Answer (score 1):

put the code

```
img = cv2.imshow('Processed',processedFrame)
out.write(processedFrame)
```

inside the `try` block

and always take care of the indentations in python.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Friday the 13th_ The Game_20170527134320.mp4') #load a video
W = cap.get(3) #get width
H = cap.get(4) #get height

#Define a new resolution 
ratio = H/W
W = 800
H = int(W * ratio)

#setup the parameters for saving the processed file
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('processedVideo.mp4',fourcc, 15.0, (int(W),int(H)))

Dx = []
Dy = []
after =0
DxAve =0
Dxold =0
DyAve =0
Dyold =0
i = 0
state = ""

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    img = scipy.misc.imresize(frame, (H,W))

    #np.array(Image.fromarray(frame,(H,W)).resize())
    #draw camera's POV
    cv2.circle(img,(int(W/2),int(H/2)),5,(0,0,255),8)
    try:
        processedFrame,dx,dy = process(img)

        if (i < 6):
            Dx.append(dx)
            Dy.append(dy)
            i=i+1
        else:
            DxAve = sum(Dx)/len(Dx)
            DyAve = sum(Dy)/len(Dy)
            del Dx[:]
            del Dy[:]
            i=0

        if (DyAve > 30) and (abs(DxAve) < 300):        
            #check if the vanishing point and the next vanishing point aren't too far from each other 
            if (((DxAve - Dxold)**2 + (DyAve - Dyold)**2) < 150**2) == True:  ##distance 150 px max 
                cv2.line(img,(int(W/2),int(H/2)),(int(W/2)+int(DxAve),int(H/2)+int(DyAve)),(0,0,255),7)
                
                #walking directions
                if abs(DxAve) < 80 and DyAve > 100 and abs(Dxold-DxAve) < 20:
                    state = 'Straight'
                    cv2.putText(img,state,(50,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3,(0,0,0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)

                elif DxAve > 80 and DyAve > 100 and abs(Dxold-DxAve) < 20:
                    state = 'Right'
                    cv2.putText(img,state,(50,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3,(0,0,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)

                elif DxAve < 80 and DyAve > 100 and abs(Dxold-DxAve) < 20:
                    state = 'Left'
                    cv2.putText(img,state,(50,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3,(0,0,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
                else:
                    cv2.line(img,(int(W/2),int(H/2)),(int(W/2)+int(Dxold),int(H/2)+int(Dyold)),(0,0,255),)
            
            #walking directions 
            if state == 'Straight':
                cv2.putText(img,state,(50,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3,(0,0,0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
            else:
                cv2.putText(img,state,(50,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3,(0,0,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)           

            Dxold = DxAve
            Dyold = DyAve

            img = cv2.imshow('Processed',processedFrame)
            out.write(processedFrame)

    except:
        print('Failed to process frame')

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q') or cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('Q'):
        break

out.release()
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

`processedFrame` is assigned in the `try` block, but that assignment may not be made if `process()` raises an exception.

You need to assign `processedFrame` before the `try` block if you want to make sure it's assigned to some value outside of the `try/except`:

```py
# Ellipses denote that the code used is the same as in the original question.
# They have been removed for brevity.
processedFrame = None
try:
    processedFrame,dx,dy = process(img)
    # ...
except:
    print('Failed to process frame')

# This should no longer produce an error.
img = cv2.imshow('Processed',processedFrame)
out.write(processedFrame)
# ...
```

Comment: Hey got some updates now there is a different error throwing up! but thanks a bunch for answering "Failed to process frame
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ragha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\crosswalk.py", line 280, in <module>
    img = cv2.imshow('Processed',processedFrame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.4) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor' "